# How do I apply a look back regex on a pattern that may have variable characters inside?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I need to gather the two values `36.12` and `25.40` in the following string:

original discount of 9.17 % (amount with discount: USD 36.12) and negociated discount of 36.12 % (amount with discount: USD 25.40), delivery in 15 days

Observe that both quantities are preceeded by the same char string `amount with discount: USD`, the labels for the desired values are `original discount` and `negociated discount`.

For the first desired value I tried `(?<=original discount of ).*\)` that correctly capture `9.17 % (amount with discount: USD 36.12)`, then appended `((?<=amount with discount: USD).*)` (resulting in full regex `(?<=original discount of ).*\)((?<=amount with discount: USD).*)` ) to capture the 36.12, but it does not work (tried the same for the second desired value, changing `original` to `negotiated`).

Any hints on this? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Capture them, see `((?:negociated|original) discount).*?\bUSD\s*([0-9.]+)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/irJlUv/1). Also, as the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using R, stringr package.

Comment: Ok, so, does `stringr::str_match_all(x, "((?:negociated|original) discount).*?\\bUSD\\s*([0-9.]+)")` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture both parts you need:

```
((?:negociated|original) discount).*?\bUSD\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/irJlUv/2)

**Details**

- `((?:negociated|original) discount)` - Group 1: either `negociated` or `original` and then a `discount` word
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\bUSD` - a whole word `USD`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: 1+ digits followed with an optional `.` and 1+ digits sequence

In R `stringr`, you may extract these values using

```
x <- "original discount of 9.17 % (amount with discount: USD 36.12) and negociated discount of 36.12 % (amount with discount: USD 25.40), delivery in 15 days"
res <- stringr::str_match_all(x, "((?:negociated|original) discount).*?\\bUSD\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)")
lapply(res, function(z) z[,-1])
```

See [an R online demo](https://rextester.com/GYV89218)

Comment: Great Wiktor, thank you. I did not know the (:? construction. Regards

Comment: How would we adjust it to accomodate comma numbers such as 1,234.56?

Comment: @FabioCorrea Maybe you do not need to use a very restrictive pattern. Just replace `\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?` with `\\d[\\d.,]*`